# Replace textarea with rich text editor in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, admin

I would like to know the best way to replace a standard textarea field with a rich text editor in Django Admin?

Answer (score 31):

There's an [add-on Django application](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-tinymce/) to provide [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) support for Django admin forms without having to muck around with admin templates or Django newform internals.

Answer (score 14):

Take a look on this [snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1035/) - basic idea is to include custom JS in your admin definitions which will replace standard text areas with rich-text editor.

For jQuery/FCKEditor such JS could look like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("textarea").each(function(n, obj) {
        fck = new FCKeditor(obj.id) ;
            fck.BasePath = "/admin-media/fckeditor/" ;
            fck.ReplaceTextarea() ;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 12):

I'd say: define your own ModelAdmin class and overwrite the widget used for particular field, like:

```
class ArticleAdminModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField(widget=widgets.AdminWYMEditor)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Article
```

(AdminWYMEditor is a `forms.Textarea` subclass that adds WYMEditor with configuration specific to Django admin app).

See [this blog post by Jannis Leidel](http://web.archive.org/web/20101123194618/http://jannisleidel.com/2008/11/wysiwym-editor-widget-django-admin-interface/) to see how this widget can be implemented.

Answer (score 8):

At the date of the post and the answers TinyMCE was quite popular (as it probably remains today).
But after some time ckeditor has appeared and many consider that a better alternative, including many SO users:

[Compare TinyMCE and CKeditor for a Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470067/compare-tinymce-and-ckeditor-for-a-wiki)

http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/tinymce-vs-ckeditor

There is also a 2013 review of WISIWYG editors with Django in Russian:

http://habrahabr.ru/company/htdt/blog/202782/

Answer (score 2):

Currently the most straight forward way to use tinymce in django admin is to use Grappelli.

http://code.google.com/p/django-grappelli/

Grappelli is also a requirement for [django-filebrowser](http://code.google.com/p/django-filebrowser/) so if you want the whole shebang you will gotta need it anyways.

Comment: let's wait for the v3 (maybe standalone of grappelli)..
meanwhile i got the bundle working with http://code.google.com/p/django-filebrowser/source/browse/branches/filebrowser3-no-grappelli/  and django-tinymce-1.5.tar.gz (latest release at this time) with this hack http://code.google.com/p/django-tinymce/issues/detail?id=40
eh.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, to update a little this post, I would say that the easiest way to implement TinyMCE is to use the [django-tinymce](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce) app. You must also download the JS files from the [TinyMCE page](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/index.php). I got some errors with the django intenationalization, but downloading the laguage packs from the TinyMCE must be enough.

Answer (score 2):

```
class KindEditor(forms.Textarea):
    class Media:
        css ={
            'all':(settings.STATIC_ROOT + 'editor/themes/default/default.css',)
        }
        js = (settings.STATIC_ROOT + 'editor/kindeditor-min.js',settings.STATIC_ROOT + 'editor/lang/zh_CN.js',)
    def __init__(self):
        attrs = {}
        attrs['rel'] = 'kind'
        super(KindEditor, self).__init__(attrs)


class NewsAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    pass

    class Meta:
        model = News
        widgets = {
            'body':KindEditor()
        }

class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = NewsAdminForm


admin.site.register(News, NewsAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2):

Install this package

```
pip install django-ckeditor
```

then run these commands to migrate.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py collectstatic
```

finally restart your Django server.

Once you complete the above steps, you can see the rich text editor in your admin panel fields.