# Standard Django way for letting users edit rich content

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a Django website in which I want site administrators to be able to edit rich content.
Suppose we're talking about an organizational info page, which might include some pictures, and some links, where the page is not as structured as a news page (which updates with news pieces every few days), but still needs the ability to be easily edited by site admins which do not necessarily want to mess with HTML (or rather, I do not want them to).

So where do I put this dynamic content? On the database? In which format? How do I make it accesible in the django default admin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use one of the existing rich-text editors**

The lightest weight would be to use something at the js level like DojoEditor:

http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AddDojoEditor

See also this thread:

[Replace textarea with rich text editor in Django Admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329963/replace-textarea-with-rich-text-editor-in-django-admin)

Answer (score 1):

For what you're describing I'd use [flatpages](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/), which is a django app that lets users create and edit pages in the admin panel.

As for formatting, I'd use [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/). Integrating it is pretty easy, [here is a walkthrough](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AddWYSIWYGEditor) (do steps 1 and 2 and jump to the bottom, "Using TinyMCE with flatpages (newforms)")