# Compare TinyMCE and CKeditor for a Wiki

Tags: django, tinymce, wiki, wysiwyg, ckeditor

For a custom wiki [django-wakawaka](http://github.com/bartTC/django-wakawaka), i want to be able to add a WYSIWYG support.

TinyMCE is obviously the most popular plugin, used even by Wordpress.

But CK-editor seems more feature full.

Those who have used either of these or both, which is better and why. Are there some better packages, that I am missing?

Is there something that I am missing when I conclude CKeditor is better, by going through them (because it is not as widely used).

I want to use it with django and jquery, with multiple instances of WYSIWYG widget per page. Does one offer advantage over the other.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I spent some time implementing CKEditor in the last couple days. I've implemented TinyMCE in the past as well. On the positive, it's far more consistent and bug-free than TinyMCE... by which I mean, where TinyMCE "feels" buggy, CKEditor has worked around awkward browser behavior to a much greater degree, making it "feel" much more solid. On the negative, if you want to extend it, the documentation is relatively sparse. I think this is mostly because CKEditor is relatively new (its API is very different from FCKEditor), and it would be reasonable to expect the CK 3.0 documentation to reach at least the quality of the FCK 2.0 docs soon.

Comment: Documentation for CKEditor plugin developers is still very poor.

Comment: @Tim Down, you are not wrong. There are still a few holes in the docs. That said, it's much better now than it was at the time I wrote that answer.

Comment: I really should contact the developers rather that whinge here, I suppose.

Comment: @Tim Down, Hell, I was thinking of volunteering a little time to write some documentation myself—after having struggled through writing my own (WebKit-only) RTE, I've been so generally impressed by CKE that I'd love to help it succeed. Unfortunately, the missing pieces are where my knowledge is absolutely weakest.

Comment: @eyelidlessness any suggestions on how to persist the tinyMCE formatted string using a form ?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247900/save-formatted-text-to-database-and-retrieve-it-back-as-is-like-a-formatted-st

Answer (score 10):

I've been using both editors since some years ago... Almost always I've chosen CKeditor over TinyMCE.
The reason?
Short answer:
CKEditor is very stable and very easy to use and has integrated the file manager (with an ad, but it is no problem for me), but TinyCE has not any integrated File manager.
Nevertheless, I like JCE editor (for Joomla), this editor is based on TinyMCE and works like a charm. It has a very good implementation of File management.
If you plan to use a WYSIWYG editor for a wiki, any of them are ok, because you don't need a filemanager (I think).
However, I recommend you, based in my experience, CKeditor.

The long answer is very long for this space. If you want the long answer, contact me or google around about this topic.

Comment: If you've got a deeper analysis, blog about it and link it here. I'd be interested in reading.

Comment: You haven't been using CKEditor for years, since it is a completely new editor (released in September 2009) that replaces FCKEditor. Any comparisons between FCKEditor and TinyMCE do not necessarily hold true for CKEditor.

Comment: CKEditor is the new name for FCKEditor, so I count with that years too. Also, I used CK since it was in alpha release. Nevertheless, the  thing is that ckEditor (as an evolutioin of FCKEditor) is a very good one editor, easy to use, easy to configure, lightweight and look beatiful (some other editor forgot to have good-looking GUI).
However you use the editor that better fulfills your needs.
Regards.

Comment: Jerph, Maybe I have a post about my analysis about some editor I've used. I'll notify you.

Answer (score 2):

A cople of other Wysiwyg editors

http://imperavi.com/redactor/ (paid - actively developed)

http://xinha.webfactional.com/ (updated 2010)

http://www.kevinroth.com/rte/ (updated 2010)

http://nicedit.com/ (updated 2008 - small fix 2012)

Comment: angelcervera's comment would be more appropriate as a comment under this answer. So here it is, perchance the answer is removed: CoffeeMonster, these editors are obsoleted:

niceedit: Last release in January 4th, 2009 and forums has a lot of posts without answers.

rte: No modifications in code since 2008. I did not found mail list history.

So, this two options are ruled out.

There are other option: xinha http://xinha.webfactional.com/ But i don't test it.

Comment: nicedit looks quite nice, but not much toolbars comparing to ckeditor, in particular no fullscreen button

Answer (score 0):

Because of the fact that my Internship has something to do with the CKEditor. I have been developing a lot with CKEditor the last 4 months. And as my research said: If we Compare TinyMCE and the CKEditor 4.x There aren't any big difference. The only differences are: CKEditor has a smoother layout and design, CKEditor has a lot bigger community (If i remember it right a difference of 13k (35k vs 50k i remember, something like that) and CKEditor has multiple developers. The last argument is an argument that i'm not sure off. But i have been told that TinyMCE is being developed by only 1 or 2 persons and the CKEditor by multiple (and an entire community!)

If you ask me, all in favor for the CKEditor.

The negative point that is stated once above, that the documentation isn't what it is used to be since the new version. I don't really agree. The only thing is that you need to read the API. With JAVA (as example) you won't find a full explanation neither. And the nice thing is that, I and many other persons are posting questions on StackOverflow. This will support all the support you need. And for the basics almost everything is there already!

And if we have a problem, there is always one of the Core developers of the CKEditor to help us out ;)

Answer (score 0):

One big bug of TinyMCE is a when you copy and paste in TinyMCE then it does not manage any space or tab and indent it to the beginning, so TinyMCE is not good but ckeditore is a more powerful editor.