# integrating Fancybox and tinyMCE problem

Tags: javascript, tinymce, fancybox

I have a problem when put tinyMCE in Fancybox popup box 
Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {


        $(".reply_button").fancybox({
        'scrolling'     : 'no',
        'titleShow'     : false,
        'onClosed'      : function() {
           $.fancybox.close();
            $("#login_error").hide();
        }
        ,'onComplete': function(){
              $("textarea.editor").tinymce({
            script_url: "resources/scripts/tiny_mce",
            mode: "textareas",
            theme: "advanced",

        });
        }
    });

    });
```

The problem is when the box opened then I close it , the grey layer that covered the page stay and i have to refresh the page to get back to the website .

and I have this error trace in the console

> Error: uncaught exception:
>   [Exception... "Node cannot be used in
>   a document other than the one in which
>   it was created"  code: "4" nsresult:
>   "0x80530004
>   (NS_ERROR_DOM_WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR)" 
>   location: ""

Comment: Any chance you could show us a jsFiddle or live link?

Comment: Works just fine in Chrome 10.0.648.204, shows the error you describe in Firefox 3 and 4.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a bug in TinyMCE. I [unpacked the script](https://github.com/downloads/mjball/Stack-Overflow-Q-A/tiny_mce.js) and it's dying on line 7687 (both halves of the `if`statement throw the error, line wrapped here for readability):

```
if (i.compareBoundaryPoints(i.START_TO_START, g.selectedRange) === 0 && 
    i.compareBoundaryPoints(i.END_TO_END, g.selectedRange) === 0)
```

---

You might want to [file a bug report](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/develop/bugtracker_bugs.php), use a [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301567/) [editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470067/), or do both. I haven't used TinyMCE myself but there seem to be a number of valid complaints about its size (bloated) and bugs (numerous).