# What should I do with tinyMCE when replacing sections of the DOM using ajaxSubmit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tabs, tinymce-3

On a multi-tab page, some tabs `submit` process changes the content of other tabs through an `ajaxSubmit`. If the other tab contains active `tinyMCE` edits what should I do to that tab before replacing it's content and what should I do (if anything) after the replacement?

Currently the code performs `tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", true, ed_id);` on all editors in the target tab and relies on the normal functionality of the system to bring them back after the change. Is that all that is necessary? I am experiencing obscure exceptions within the `tinyMCE` code after the change but it is difficult to discover the cause.

The error itself is *SCRIPT5022: IndexSizeError - tiny_mce.js (1,78075)* but I doubt that is specifically relevant.

*TinyMCE v3.4.5*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10096122/1544886

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference but I'd use `tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", false, ed_id);` anyway

Comment: @KScandrett - Why - what is the difference? A quick poke around in the code suggests that the `remove` method ignores the 2nd parameter. Thanks for the interest anyway.

Comment: I don't know. I did look into that but couldn't get a definitive answer. I see both values used, so yeah I don't expect it makes a difference, but wanted to throw it out there just in case. The "mceRemoveControl" examples however on the tinymce official site pass `false`.

Comment: TinyMCE does not play nice with AJAX I have spending along time trying to hack it to work nice and effectivly i gave up and started using CKEditor you just need to remove CKEditor before changes then re initialise it when you have finished or the AJAX has returned

Answer (score 4):

As i said in my Comments TinyMCE does not play well with AJAX there are loads of problems with it i have tried many times to get it to work.

In the end i switched to CKEditor so if you would like to try and use it you can here is the code you need for the `ajaxSubmit()` options

```
beforeSubmit:function{
   for(var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        try{
            CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].destroy();
        }catch(e){
        }
    }
}
```

the above code will remove CKEditor cleanly before you submit the following is how to re-inistialize CKEditor when your ajax has finished again this is a option for `ajaxSubmit()`:

```
success:function(){
    // do what you need to update your DOM and then final call is
    $("editorSelector").ckeditor(options);
}
```