# Using Rich Text Editor in Django admin with tinymice

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and am trying to use **tinymice_3.5.8** to replace the text area of django admin with rich text editor. I have added the url pattern of tinymice in the
**urls.py** file of the site as

```
url(r'^tiny_mce/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',
{ 'document_root': 'C:/tinymce_3.5.8/tinymce/jscripts/'})
```

and I have copied the change_form.html file of the django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/ directory to my template directory and added the following code in the file.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="C:/tinymce_3.5.8/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
  mode: "textareas",
  theme: "simple"
});
</script>
```

after the line

```
{{media}}
```

This should have replaced the old text area of the **Django site admin, Add flat page**, with the rich text editor, but is not showing any changes. The text area remains the same. I have also studied similar questions in this site but could not get anything. Hope to get some help!

Comment: Does the browser even load javascript file? Im asking since src attribute is a windows path.

Comment: Look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329963/replace-textarea-with-rich-text-editor-in-django-admin).This link might help you...

Comment: @Bula ok, I got it. The issue is with the path. But it is still not working even if I copy the js file to the working directory.

Comment: Try to copy `langs/en.js` and `themes/simple/editor_template.js` into folder where you have `tiny_mce.js`, leave them in appropriate subfolders. Check if firebug reports any error on the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce - It's a tinymce module especially for django. You use it like this:

in a models.py:

```
from tinymce.models import HTMLField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    text = HTMLField()
```

And it works in the django admin too.

Comment: I have created only site using django. There is no app in it. So, there is no models.py file to change. Anyway, thanks for your answer.